# Options for automating data off loading from teradata to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, loading, etl, sqoop

I am aware that Sqoop can be used to pull the data from sources such as teradata .But could you guys give any suggestion how to do data loading from teradata to hadoop with less man hours when there are hundreds of tables present.

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Voted to close as too broad as this is nearly asking the explanation of a whole field, rather than being a specific programming question. -- Consider asking teradata or your implementation partner, they can probably give strategic options.